# Is there any way to change order status when order success page is displayed?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I'm facing an issue on triggering SMS(Using a 3rd party extenstion) when an order is placed successfully.
SMS is triggering before the payment(Instamojo Payment gateway) is getting completed.

```
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
```

Can I set something like above in **success.phtml** file?

**Payment Gateway Code**

```
if($payment_status === "Credit"){
Mage::log("Payment was successfull for $insta_id", Zend_Log::DEBUG, $this->LOG_FILE_NAME);
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
Mage::log("Pending payment is set to False", Zend_Log::DEBUG, $this->LOG_FILE_NAME);
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
$order->setEmailSent(true);
$order->save();

$payment = $order->getPayment();
$transaction = $payment->getTransaction($transactionId);  
$data = $transaction->getAdditionalInformation();
$url = $data['raw_details_info']['Url'];
$transaction->setAdditionalInformation(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS,
                    array('InstmojoId'=> $insta_id,
                          'Context'=>'Token payment',
                          'Amount'=>$amount,
                          'Status'=>1,
                          'Url'=>$url))->save();
$transaction->setParentTxnId($insta_id)->save();
$payment->setIsTransactionClosed(1);

$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save order after setState:

```
 $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();
```

Comment: It is saving I guess, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a custom order Status  **Payment Completed** and updated it before Saving the order.

> $order->setStatus("Payment Completed")->save();

```
if($payment_status === "Credit"){
            Mage::log("Payment was successfull for $insta_id", Zend_Log::DEBUG, $this->LOG_FILE_NAME);
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
            Mage::log("Pending payment is set to False", Zend_Log::DEBUG, $this->LOG_FILE_NAME);
            $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
            $order->setEmailSent(true);
            $order->setStatus("Payment Completed")->save();

            $payment = $order->getPayment();
            $transaction = $payment->getTransaction($transactionId);
            $data = $transaction->getAdditionalInformation();
            $url = $data['raw_details_info']['Url'];
            $transaction->setAdditionalInformation(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS,
                array('InstmojoId'=> $insta_id,
                    'Context'=>'Token payment',
                    'Amount'=>$amount,
                    'Status'=>1,
                    'Url'=>$url))->save();
            $transaction->setParentTxnId($insta_id)->save();
            $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(1);
            $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));

        }
```